# Get all Comment ID's within a Drupal node

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

I have a node in Drupal with a few comments. Is there an easyish way to get the CID of every comment within the node? Also, is there a way to sort them by various parameters, chronology, karma of the comment etc. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try views? http://drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you should check the comment_render function.

But if you need your own sort parameter, it'd be easier to do it using sql commands;

Check: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/comment_render/6

You can first make a query listing all the cid's on whatever you need to order;

```
$myquery = 'SELECT c.cid, c.pid, c.nid, c.subject, c.comment, c.format, c.timestamp, c.name, c.mail, c.homepage, u.uid, u.name AS registered_name, u.signature, u.picture, u.data, c.status FROM {comments} c INNER JOIN {users} u ON c.uid = u.uid WHERE c.nid
= %d ORDER BY c.uid ASC';

$myresult = db_query($myquery)
```

This query exists on the comment_render function. But I tried to modify it for my use.

Now we have the **node id** and the **cid**s in the order we wanted.

Here is the rendering work;

```
while ($mycomments = mysql_fetch_row($myresult)){

foreach ($mycomment as $mycid)

comment_render($nid, $mycid)

}
```

I haven't tested this one, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can load all comments for a node in drupal 7 using the function:

`comment_get_thread($node, $mode, $comment_per_page)`

Check out the documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_get_thread/7

It also discusses the default sort parameter. This does not however give you an easy way to resort the comments. I would just use views for that. Then you can use hook_node_view to disable the default comment display and add views_embed_view('my_view', 'my_display');

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

```
$sql = "SELECT cid FROM {comments} WHERE nid=%d ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$resource = db_query($sql, $node->nid);
while( $row = db_fetch_array( $resource ) ) {
  print comment_render( $node->nid, $row['cid'] );
}
```

Our initial SQL query only needs to fetch the comment ID (cid) as comment_render's second parameter will handle fetching all the additional information.